# Access to object's method in list of objects

Tags: javascript

I have list of objects. Each object has some methods and properties, like

> myObject.SetValue(20);

i need to create 3, 5 or more objects and store them in list. This is how I'm doing it:

```
 var listOfObj = [];
 for (var x = 0; x<3; x++)
 {
    listOfObj[x] = new myObject({ id: "obj" + x + ""});
 }
```

So, i had created array of 3 elements and each elemet is object.

Now I want to access to methods and/or properties of object, for example:

```
obj1.Refresh();
```

How to do that? Is it possible?
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

Just access your objects via the array index, and invoke the functions:

```js
const obj0 = {
  add: (a, b) => a + b
}

const arr = [];

arr[0] = obj0;

console.log(arr[0].add(1,2));
```

Answer (score 1):

#### ES 5:

```js
    function myObject(v){
        this.id= "obj " + v;
        this.value = 0;
        this.that = this;
        this.SetValue = function(val){ //functions need context.
            this.value = val; // use "that" as this
        }
        this.getValue = ()=>this.value; // lambda functions inherit context
    
        this.Refresh = function(args){
            //do stuff
            console.log("Refreshed!");
        }
    }
    
     var listOfObj = [];
     for (var x = 0; x<3; x++)
     {
        listOfObj.push(new myObject(x));
        listOfObj[x].SetValue(x);
        console.log(listOfObj[x].getValue());
     }
```

#### ES 6:

Snippet not supported

```
class myObject {
  constructor(v){
    this.id= "obj " + v;
    this.value = 0;
    this.that = this;
  }      
  this.SetValue = (val)=> {that.value = val;};
  this.getValue = ()=>this.value;
    
  this.Refresh = function(args){
    //do stuff. use "that" as this
    console.log("Refreshed!");
  }
}

var listOfObj = [];
for (var x = 0; x<3; x++)
{
  listOfObj.push(new myObject(x));
  listOfObj[x].SetValue(x);
  console.log(listOfObj[x].getValue());
}
```

This will instantiate Objects using myObject as constructor. As requested.